# Access object inside an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

This is how my response body looks like. 
Its stored in a variable and when i use 
console.log(body) I get the following.

```
[
   {
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3"
   }
]
```

Im trying to access "key3" using the following

```
console.log(body[0].key3)
```

I get undefined. Im not sure what is wrong here. If i just do

`console.log(body[0])`

im getting a string `[`

Thanks for your help here.

Comment: the response you are getting is probably a string. you'd have to do something like JSON.parse(body) first

Comment: looks like your `body` isn't actually that object, but a JSON (string) representation. Try `JSON.parse` on it first.

Comment: Thanks guys! Like the everyone mentioned its a string. I was a able to use the solutions given below.

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem Explained

Your JS is looking at the property on a specific character:

Take a look at the following example that will help demonstrate what is going on:

```js
const string = 'Hello';
console.log(string[0] === 'H'); // true
console.log('H'.key3 === undefined); // true
```

---

#### The Solution

You need to `JSON.parse` the string:

```js
const body = `
[
   {
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3"
   }
]
`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(parsed[0].key3);
```

Comment: Nitpick: The return value of `JSON.parse` is not JSON

Answer (score 1):

`body` sounds like it's a string - `JSON.parse` it to an object:

```js
var body = '[{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2","key3": "value3"}]';
console.log(body[0]);
body = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(body[0].key3);
```